# Setting default onclick behavior for <img> tag in generated html

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, sencha-touch

So i have a web app I have been building, and I receive generated html from a server for a post, and place it within the body. My question is: is there a way to set a default onclick behavior for the  tag within that message? I'd rather avoid parsing through the html and setting behavior for each tag. I may just be having a brain fart but felt its best just to ask. The goal behind this is to enable a card switch to full screen the image. I just cant figure out how to set the click behavior. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Ext JS component to do this. Any number of the Ext components will work this way but the base Component is all that is needed.

Once the server returns the html data, use the Component's update method.  Bind to the click event of the Component's html element and then any html element that is clicked inside of the component will fire the click event.  Within the function bound to the event, the event object will be available and will tell you what was clicked.

```
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        var htmlContainer,
            htmlFromServer;

        /*
         * you can create a component that will be 
         * be used to set the html into the page
         * while allowing it to be managed from Ext JS
         */
        htmlContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 400,
            height: 400
        });

        /*
         * this would be html from your service call
         * this is just a simplified example
         */
        htmlFromServer = '<div>Click this Div and this will be the event target. Click the image and that will be the value of the event target.</div><img src="http://www.sencha.com/img/apple-touch-icon.png" /><span>And this is some span-wrapped content.</span>';

        /* update the component with the html you want it to contain */
        htmlContainer.update(htmlFromServer);

        /* bind to the click event of the components html element */
        htmlContainer.getEl().on('click', function (event) { console.log('event object and html element that was clicked:', event, event.target)});

    });​
```

Answer (score 3):

Most js libraries have a binding service function...

in extJS it's apparently

```
Ext.select('img').on('click', function);
```

Use a css selector in place of 'img', and you can do images with a certain class, or of a certain ID, or really whatever you like.

[Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-on)

Comment: This. Also, if your container has an ID, `Ext.create('Ext.Panel', { id: 'SomePanel'});` you can target the images with `Ext.select('#SomePanel img')` - Ext.select() gives you a group of matching elements back - .on() to the whole group _should_ work but if not you can `Ext.select('blah').each(...)` the elements as well. *Edit:* Oh, you can also do (assuming MyPanel is your component): `MyPanel.getEl().select()` for specific targeting too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a number of ways, but if the images you want to add click events to are stored in a center element, retrieve that element(via document.getElementByTagName, byId, byClassName, etc), then you could do the following:

```
// Create a few variables to help us out
var index = 0,
    imgs = centerEle.getElementsByTagName("img"),
    eventType = "addEventListener", // Default event listener function
    eventPrefix = ""; // default prefix for event names

// IE event model support:
if (!document.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener")) {
    eventType = "attachEvent";
    eventPrefix = "on";
}

// Loop through images in the central element
for (var a = 0; a < imgs.length; a += 1) {
    /* if you wanted to exclude certain iamges:
    if (img[a].src !== "http://somesite.com/img.jpg" && 
        img[a].src !== "http://somesite.com/img2.jpg") { */

    img[a][eventType](eventPrefix + "click",function(evnt) {
        // 'this' is the img
        // evnt is the event that was raised
        // everything within this function will be called when the image is clicked
    });
    // }
}
```

A few notes:

Instead of taking the easy way out, I used an event listener instead of `onclick` this is because if the element already has a `onclick` event specified any later specified `onclick` properties will overwrite the previous one.

Along with using event listeners instead of event properties, I included IE support. This is why I included the `eventType` and `eventPrefix` variables

Answer (score 0):

You can get the all the IMGs in your page using `document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")` or using jquery selector and associate your default click handler with `onclick` event on each IMG element. (for exact syntax of how to do it with jquery, you can refer to a manual).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what jQuery's `.live()` ([< jq 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) and `.on()` ([>= jq 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) methods are for.  You can use this to bind events to elements that do not exist at the time of binding.